# Some questions about javascript prototypes and constructors

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype

If I have the JavaScript function:

```
function Person(){}
```

1. After this what is the value of `Person.prototype`?
2. What is the difference between `Person.constructor` and `Person.prototype.constructor`?

If I have the code:

```
function Student(){}
Student.prototype = new Person()
Student.prototype.constructor = Student
```

3. Why in inheriting Student from Person must I set `Student.prototype.constructor` to `Student`?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question are explained in micro detail so have look at this article , its one of the best article [Prototype](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/ch5.md).i have used all my answer from that article

> After this what is the value of Person.prototype?

```
 function Person(){}
```

Whenever a function is defined, it has a property called ***prototype** which is non enumerable.

This prototype property is an ***Object*** which has non enumerable property called ***constructor*** which is ***writable*** , ***configurable***.

This constructor is just a reference to Function itself which is ***Person*** in this case 
so if you check `Person.prototype.constructor == Person` or `Person.constructor == Person`. it will return true. (The later one is same as first expression, by property delegation) this answers your second question.

> What is the difference between Person.constructor and Person.prototype.constructor?

Javascript property delegation , when u try to access a property which is not present in object, it ll try to check in its prototype link.

when u try to access a property called `x` on Person.prototype object.

it will check in Person.prototype first, since there is not property called x. it will check in parent. which ***Object.prototype*** (Where all the objects are prototyped. This will be last ancestor in your ancestor chain)

> Third question is about creating subclass or object inheriting Person Class

By default Student function has prototype object. When executing this statement `new Person()` will create an object and pass the created object's reference to `Person.call(this)` and link the object prototype to 
Person.prototype.
Student.prototype = new Person()
This methodology is used to mimic Subclass inheritance . Such that new object created from ***new Student()** can also access ***Person*** Class methods and variable thru prototype linking.

`Student.prototype.constructor = Student`

The need for this statement is when u create a new Student object to check inheritance , such that the new object is instanceof Student Class

`var bob = new Student()`

so when u want to check that ***bob instanceof Student***. At background this will do `bob.constructor == Student`. Since bob doesn't have constructor property it will delegate and check in Student.

If your mind is still not clear with this answer . Please refer the above link. about Prototype

Answer (score 0):

> 1. After this what is the value of Person.prototype?

An object with a property `constructor` that points to the function object.

> 2. What is the difference between Person.constructor and Person.prototype.constructor?

One is part of the function object, while the other one is part of the prototype object which will be used to chain prototypes. When you use the `new` operand on Person, this new object won't inherit `constructor`.

```
function Student(){}
 Student.prototype = new Person()
 Student.prototype.constructor = Student
```

You are creating an instance of Person and assigning it to be the Prototype of Student. By doing so, you are also inheriting the constructor of Person, you'll probably want to use the constructor of Student.

By creating a new object of Person, you are also able to specify the constructor. Otherwise if you'd done `Student.prototype = Person.prototype` and then `Student.prototype.constructor = Student` you would have also changed `Person.prototype.constructor` to `Student`.

You are still calling out the constructor which is the `function` you are using `new` on.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Person(){}
```

1. What is the value of Person.prototype ?

   - When a function is created, prototype property is set to that function as an empty object.
   - This prototype property(empty object) comes into play when an instance of that function is created.
   - For the newly created instance,

     ```
      instance.__proto__ or Object.prototypeOf(instance) would return the Person.prototype
     ```
   - Basically, created instance's parent is Person.prototype
2. Person.constructor and Person.prototype.constructor

   - These two are completely different. To start with,

     ```
     constructor is not Person's property, it is inherited from Person.__proto__.
     ```
   - Person.prototype.constructor again comes into play when an instance is created using Person. All the instances created using Person will share the same constructor which is nothing but the Person function itself
   - We will run into circular reference if we keep going on

     ```
     Person.prototype.constructor.prototype..... This is because, Person.protoype.constructor refers to Person function itself
     ```
3. Why Set Student.prototype.constructor=Student ?

   - Case1: Without Setting the Constructor

     - ```
        s = new Student();
       s.constructor // returns function Person(){}
       ```
     - This is because, when an instance is created, instance will not own constructor property, it just inherits from prototype, in this case prototype is Person object, so,

       ```
       s.constructor which is s.prototype.constructor would show function Person(){}
       ```
   - Case2: With Setting the Constructor

     - When Student.prototype.constructor is set to Student, all instances created would correctly show function Student(){} when s.prototype.constructor or s.constructor is checked.